# clang: backslash and newline separated by space in single line comment

Tags: c++, clang

Why this ([live](http://rextester.com/XCXKS73869)):

```
int main()
{
    // my pretty comment /\   
    //
    // 


}
```

gives the warning on clang:

```
warning: backslash and newline separated by space [-Wbackslash-newline-escape]
```

?

Looks like that code is perfectly valid without any pitfalls.

Comment: A backslash directly followed by a newline "escapes" / removes the newline. The two lines are joined. It is not obvious from something like your code that this is *not* the case, since the spaces are ... invisible.

Comment: @dyp, maybe I had bad question, but I wanted to ask, why we need  such warning there ? Yes, it will be the problem in situation like [this](http://rextester.com/IHZI95248), but it's useless in the case above

Comment: I'd guess the code that triggers the warning (the compiler diagnostic) simply does not attempt to detect when it's not an actual issue. Such heuristics are often complicated, and might produce false negatives.

Comment: Because this is dangerous. And it is not clear what you really meant (maybe you have put this space there accidentally). Some invisible change to the code (removing a space) can change the meaning of the code dramatically. Also be aware that many code styles require removal of trailing spaces, and some editors can do that automatically.

Comment: Just add a space before that newline and after backslash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the C++14 draft [[4296]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

**2.2 Phases of translation [lex.phases]**

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character () immediately followed by a new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to
>      form logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical
>      source line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. Except
>      for splices reverted in a raw string literal, if a splice results in a
>      character sequence that matches the syntax of a
>      universal-character-name, the behavior is undefined. A source file
>      that is not empty and that does not end in a new-line character, or
>      that ends in a new-line character immediately preceded by a backslash
>      character before any such splicing takes place, shall be processed as
>      if an additional new-line character were appended to the file.

Exactly the first sentence of it gives your warning.

In your example code:

```
int main()
{
    // my pretty comment /\
    int x;
    int y = x;    
}
```

the `int x;` line will be joined into a comment in the line above and will be removed in next phases of translation. So you got a error:

> error: use of undeclared identifier 'x'

However

```
int main()
{
    // my pretty comment /\   
    //
}
```

is valid and will not cause a error. You may note that `g++` (without `-Wall`) will not give a warning here. It looks like useless warning but I think compiler may treat it as possible fail of the new line character escaping. So, it is just better to give you warning here.

> Do we need this warning there ?

Actually, no, we don't need it here. But it is just a diagnostic warning and it is better to have such warning to be able to detect possible problems than not to have it at all.

I think, here is also a reason such as:

1. People don't usually escape `spaces`. Why? :)
2. For multi-line comments here are `/*` and `*/` sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is most definitely NOT perfectly valid without any pitfalls.

A backslash at the end of the line is used to merge two source code lines. A backslash at the end of the line but with a space in between is most likely a failed attempt to merge two source code lines and therefore deserves a pretty hard warning.

Now in your case, the backslash is just there to confuse people. Which is much worse, so remove it.

Comment: But it's in a comment, the compiler should recognize people draw in comments and let these ones pass